# Trigger analytics event in the past with a specified date

Tags: google-analytics, analytics

I'm capturing the date of a product installation when user extends a trial, and pass it to a thank you page as a parameter. Then I capture it and want to retroactively trigger event in the past.

From docs the code looks like:
`ga('send', 'event', [eventCategory], [eventAction], [eventLabel], [eventValue], [fieldsObject]);`

And nothing is said about ability to set any dates.

Is there a way to do it?

Comment: I don't understand; you want GA to register an event in the past? Or just want to add a past date to an event?

Comment: I want to register an event in the past like user installed a product.

Comment: ..so it would seem like the event happened on moment of trial start, instead of moment of extension? The why is still kind of fuzzy to me.

Comment: User installs app via 3rd party site, so basically it's not possible to track the moment of install. But when user extends trial it's possible to get such info. And this info I want to fire as an event.

Comment: Couldn't you pass the install date as a custom dimension and the extension as an event though?

Comment: Yep, I guess there's no other option, thanks anyway

Answer (score 0):

You can not push any events retroactively in Google Analytics.

All data is connected to the time that they were sent on.

Comment: That's not 100% true - you can use  the queue time parameter to send an interaction with an offset time (https://developers.google.com/analytics/devguides/collection/protocol/v1/parameters#qt). However that works only for a couple of hours (more than 4 hours offset is not guaranteed to work), so it probably won't help with the OPs use case.